# Covariance of data versus distribution

Tags: dataset, covariance

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$I am getting hung up on what is probably a very basic point. We know that covariance is *defined* as 
$$\Cov(X,Y) = E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$$
Now if we look at the definition of expected value, assuming $X,Y$ are discrete with **mean 0**
$$\Cov(X,Y) = \sum_{(x_i,y_i)}x_iy_iP(X=x_i,Y=y_i)$$ 
Now, go read any book on statistics and they will say that 
$$\Cov(X,Y) = \sum_i x_i y_i$$ 
without any mention of the distribution. Why do we no longer care about $P(X=x_i,Y=y_i)$?
Is it because we *observed* $x_i,y_i$in the data so it happens with probability 1?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a factor $\frac{1}{n}$ missing in the last formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability doesn't disappear; it's the $\frac{1}{n}$ term.

- Let $P$ be the true probability measure.
- Let $Q$ be the the [empirical measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_measure), the probability measure implicitly defined by your random sample.

#### What is the empirical measure Q?

If you have $n$ independent observations and a set of unique, observed outcomes $\mathcal{A}$, that is, $\mathcal{A} = \left\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \right\}$

$$Q(X = x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}\frac{1}{n}: & \text{if $x$ belongs to the sample $\mathcal{A}$}\\ 0 :& \text{otherwise}\end{array} \right.$$

Note: If observations occur multiple times, then the probability would be $\frac{k}{n}$ where $k$ is the number of times that observation $x$ appeared in the sample.

#### Application to calculating the mean:

What is the mean according to empirical measure $Q$?

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}^Q\left[X\right] &= \sum_{x \in \mathcal{A}} x \,Q(X = x) \\
&= \sum_{x \in \mathcal{A}} x \frac{1}{n}\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{x \in \mathcal{A}} x
\end{align*}

Note also that $\sum_{x \in \mathcal{A}} x$ is just another way to write $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ since $\mathcal{A} = \left\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \right\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The formula $\displaystyle \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$ is valid if $\Pr((X,Y)=(x_i,y_i)) = \dfrac 1 n.$ That is the **empirical distribution.**